# Exibir PDF após chamada AJAX com TCPDF no Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Após eu salvar informações no banco de dados utilizando  o código a seguir.

```
$this->anamnese->create($input);
```

Eu chamo apenas para teste um código para gerar um PDF de teste com o código a seguir.

```
PDF::SetTitle('Hello World');
PDF::AddPage();
PDF::Write(0, 'Hello World');

$name = '/test.pdf';

$headers = array(
      'Content-Type: application/pdf',
    );

$filename = storage_path() . $name;

PDF::Output($filename);
return $filename;
```

E na callback da requisição AJAX exibo um alert de confirmação.

Porém analisando o inspecionar elemento, na aba network, recebo a response a seguir

```
%PDF-1.7
%����
7 0 obj
<< /Type /Page /Parent 1 0 R /LastModified (D:20141016181750-03'00') /Resources 2 0 R /MediaBox [0.000000 0.000000 595.276000 841.890000] /CropBox [0.000000 0.000000 595.276000 841.890000] /BleedBox [0.000000 0.000000 595.276000 841.890000] /TrimBox [0.000000 0.000000 595.276000 841.890000] /ArtBox [0.000000 0.000000 595.276000 841.890000] /Contents 8 0 R /Rotate 0 /Group << /Type /Group /S /Transparency /CS /DeviceRGB >> /Annots [ 6 0 R ] /PZ 1 >>
endobj
8 0 obj
<</Filter /FlateDecode /Length 295>> stream
x���Qo�0���+Σ��ۖ���9]|r[�-Q_&H�`�d  ٿ_%AQ�1p�
�m���ˁ�6�s�_X��+�9����`* �Sp[<9Fw��p?�#]vM���[FG�j�a�c��1)؋z�%���E�u�U�2
&4�L��,G�i�x/�<�������:Z��R�-�/�*-���p����QUU�g��lyQf��j��|7�����
�CI�I����z�C nt��u��*�Bm��V�k�ȚV9��л���~��_�*�҈����8�D�p;�� ���|�o
endstream
endobj
```

Já tentei colocar os headers e não consigo exibir ou forçar o download do PDF, porém testando sem AJAX em uma requisição à uma rota com apenas o código para gerar o PDF, ele gera e exibe no navegador normalmente.

Gostaria que, após o insert no banco, fosse gerado um PDF e aberto em nova aba, com as informações para impressão.

Ou outra solução para gerar PDF ou impressão.

Comment: Já tentou na callback de sucess fazer um get em uma rota diferente que só baixa o pdf ?

Comment: Então pensei nisso, mas por exemplo, o arquivo está na pasta storage, como faria uma rota para ele ?

Comment: Seria algo parecido como isso, substituindo o caminho do $file - http://stackoverflow.com/a/20415796/2099835

Answer (score 2):

Para que o navegador saiba que o conteúdo é para ser descarregado, deverás utilizar o cabeçalho [`Content-Disposition`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.5.1) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="meuFicheiro.pdf"
```

Adicionalmente, de acordo com as regras, deverá preferencialmente ser enviado o cabeçalho:

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

Para basicamente indicar a navegador:

> Eu não sei o que isto é, chama a caixa de diálogo `Salvar como` e usa se possivel o nome `meuFicheiro.pdf`.

Digo em cima "preferencialmente" porque supostamente o navegador ao ler a *stream* do PDF deverá identificar a mesma como um PDF, embora, por via das duvidas, como os dois cabeçalhos damos a indicação completa que é um documento para guardar no dispositivo do utilizador.

## Cabeçalho de identificação do documento

Também podes no cabeçalho `Content-Type` indicar que é um documento PDF:

```
Content-Type: application/pdf
```

## Laravel

Em alternativa, o Laravel contém um método para indicar que a resposta é um download:

```php
return Response::download($caminhoParaFicheiro, $nomeFicheiro, $cabecalhos);
```

Ver a documentação em: [Laravel: Special Responses](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#special-responses) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>

Comment: Tentei tudo isso, e quando dou o window.open no success do ajax aparece aqueles códigos ainda